# Questions about best search terms for a query in a search engine

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, google

Which Stack Exchange site would be the best to ask a question regarding the ramifications of using different permutations of search terms within the query? (This question would be an example of itself in relation to the title question)

For example, my specific question that I would like help with is: What search can I perform to get a streaming app result on Google?

I've tried using the example that I've seen in articles: "hotel right now in Chicago", from both the mobile web version of Google.com, as well as the Google app.

I don't believe that this question is suited for the Android forum, as the search result should be able to be streamed via ios as well.

Answer (score 1):

I received an alert that someone had answered/commented on this question recommending the [web applications Stack Exchange site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) (thank you for your help with the correct lingo, hde226868), but I don't see that comment or answer now...

From the web applications site:

> What topics can I ask about here?
> Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application:
>
> - Bookmarklets
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The help page at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help was very useful. I looked for a general Stack Exchange help page that I could have used before I asked my question, but https://stackexchange.com/help does not exist.

Thank you to whomever suggested the web applications Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That might not be a perfect fit since I believe the streaming app feature is only available via mobile web on Android.

Comment: I have not seen any note of compatibility (or incompatibility) in the reports regarding which devices/browsers support the streaming app feature, so I had assumed it would be like streaming video, and work across platform.

Comment: I admit I don't really have enough information about it. (Which is why I deleted my answer.)

Comment: I think your suggestion of asking the question in web apps was the correct answer. You should resubmit it with reasoning so I can accept it.